# Transactional replication support in DB2

Tags: db2, database-replication

Does DB2 support transactional replication?  Specifically, what database-level options exist in DB2 to support active-active-active setup?

Comment: Yes DB2 supports transactional replication. There are several options available by means of the [InfoSphere Data Replication product](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_10.2.1/pv_welcome.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F9&lang=en).

Comment: Also, depending on *why* you are looking to do this replication you could consider the built-in features called pureScale or HADR.